# How to handle a system.img file size larger than the partition size declared inside BoardConfig.mk file?

Tags: android

while trying to build my image, I am getting the following error:  "ext4_allocate_best_fit_partial: failed to allocate 20001 blocks, out of space?"

I don't want to change the partition table inside bootloader of dev as there are other dependencies. What other solutions I can explore.